# Update model from database per .edmx doesn't update model/cols if deleted from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

When I delete a column from an already existing db from an already existing database model, right clicking on the .edmx "Update model from Database" does not remove deleted columns from the model (column existed in the model and db before but was removed from db) .

One thing that I have noticed is that my mapping detals are not matching up with my .edmx.  Mapping detals are up to date with database but they dont' match that of the .edmx.

Is this expected behavior?  Thanks!

[Using asp.net 4.0/EF4.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that, when I update the underlying database table, the best approach is to delete the mapped table from the edmx designer, and then do `Update Model from Database`.