# Entity Framework 6.1 delete a column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on an application with Entity Framework (current version 6.1.1) Database-first and Sql Express 2008 as a storage. I have a very simple model that consists of two tables Foo and FooElements with one-to-many relations.

I have deleted column Bla from table Foo, opened my .edmx file, right-clicked an empty space and selected "Update model from the database", but the deleted field remained in the model.

When I try getting the Foo entities from the DB, an exception is thrown: Invalid column name Bla. So I deleted the whole Foo entity from the model, added it from the DB again, now I have another exception - property Bla does not exist.

I tried restarting Visual Studio, removing obj and bin files, removing the data model from the project completely and creating it from scratch - it requires property Bla in the model, but fails when I create it manually (column Bla is not created automatically hence the column does not exist in the DB).

The only solution to make my project running again is to create column Bla in the DB again and leave it there, despite the fact that I don't need it.

Is there any way to delete a column from a DB so that the Entity framework can work afterwards?
Is there any kind of cache file that I have to clean up?
Thank you.

P.S. Even thought the field does not exist in the edmx file, Entity framework still thinks it is required. Where can it get an idea, that there are still certain fields in the DB?

Comment: Did you rebuild your solution after those steps?

Comment: Yes. I even cleaned up obj and bin folder just in case.

Comment: Have you tried adding that table back into the .EDMX file?

Comment: That is exactly the problem, when I add it back - the field is not there and the exception about the missing property is thrown when I try to use it. I have exception text in German here, but the meaning is that property Bla is not found in class Foo.

Comment: the unwated field is also removed from .edmx file correct?

Comment: One possible solution might work to the close model, right click and open as XML. Then remove the reference manually.

Comment: If you just started the project, I would recommend not using edmx at all, this will give you a lot of headache down the road.

Comment: Yes, I opened the .edmx file in the text editor and I see that the field is not there.

Comment: J.W. - how do I use EntityFramework without using a .edmx file?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of question: [Entity Framework 6 Update from Database ignores deleted columns, type changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544605/entity-framework-6-update-from-database-ignores-deleted-columns-type-changes). You may also want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409083).

Comment: This is a much better alternative :https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838?SRC=VSIDE, it will allow you create code first classes from database.

Comment: Thank you László. I have read both questions and answers, one of them suggests deleting the table from the model and creating it back. I did exactly that and it did not help. Another one suggests clicking "Run Custom Tool" on edmx and tt files, also does not help me.

Comment: @AndreasKoder - Look at my answer. Seems trivial, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your ideas.

The problem was even more trivial than I expected. Another project in my sandbox solution had Entity Framework referencing the same table in the DB and it had the same model name, and since I completely forgot about it, I did not update it, and the .edmx file in the second project contained the old deleted fields. It never came to my mind that two different assemblies could interfere like that, but they did.

The solution is to remove (or rename) the model in the second project and it is working now.

Comment: Great to hear. Anyway, the solution I gave and what you state here, should work for others coming across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently.

Try manually running an **`Update-database`** with **`-force`** (Do this even if your're using Automatic Migrations):

PUT BACK **Bla** column manually to the DB, ALSO REMOVE the **Bla** field from your model and run:

```
Update-database -verbose -force -ConfigurationTypeName Configuration
```

You can Put instead of **"Confiuration"** your configuration name.

In some cases, like when there are multiple configurations, you'd have to specify the configuration full path like this:

```
AppName.MigrationsNameSpace.ConfigurationName
```

(most time would simply be **"Configuration"** where the "ConfigurationName" is)

Comment: Just edited my answer. The **Bla** column should be in the DB and  removed from the model, when running the `Update-database`.