# How to use migrations after adding a Key attribute to a property?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Package Manager Console:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

> p6.DAL.Password: : EntityType 'Password' has no key defined. Define
>   the key for this EntityType. password: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'password' is based on type 'Password' that has no keys defined.

Class Password:

```
public class Password
{
    [Key]
    public int PasswordID { get; set; }
    public string PasswordName { get; set; }
    public string IsValid { get; set; }
    public virtual Person person { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info? Have you added a new property with `[Key]` or did you decorate an existing one? Can you also show us your model?

Comment: I have decorated an existing property and hat's why he throws this error.

Comment: are you using automatic migrations ? if so, the `-force` might help. See my answer and a link to another answer of mine (not the only answer on that page, so look it down there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `-force` like this:

```
Update-database -verbose -force -ConfigurationTypeName Configuration
```

You can Put instead of `"Configuration"` your configuration name.

There's a chance my answer here would help you:

[Entity Framework 6.1 delete a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467735/entity-framework-6-1-delete-a-column/26470684#26470684)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand. what you are trying to do is to migrate the database adding the new property.in this case run this command:

Update-Database

Comment: But that's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to add a migration and that's the eroor he has given me. So I can't even update the database.

Comment: up in your First Question .there is password and Password. did you copy paste that error or you wrote it manually.my point is that perhaps you changed something from p To P..No?